# Michelson Morley experiment?

Tags: special-relativity, experimental-physics

- Its not that I question the conclusions reached concerning the Michelson–Morley experiment, however I would like to know how the following issue was addressed please?

If I could pass bob through a beam splitter, and have each copy of him pace out each leg of the interferometer at say $2~\rm{km/hr}$. However if along one of the legs, there was an escalator aiding his initial progress at $1~\rm{km/hr}$.

Okay, so they each leave the beam splitter at the same time, however aided by the escalator one of them moves at $3~\rm{km/hr}$, and reaches the mirror at the end of his leg earlier than the other. But on the return journey he is inhibited by progression of the escalator, and moves at $1~\rm{km/hr}$. So the other bob who travelled at $2~\rm{km/hr}$ the whole time, makes up ground on the other bob on the return journey, and they arrive home at the same time as each other.

- With so many clever people working on this experiment over the years, I know there must be a contingency for this issue. If somebody can inform me please?

Comment: Trouble with homework? Tell us what you have tried on your own and we can try to help you.

Comment: Thank you. For purposes of conceptualizing the Michelson Morley experiment, I dont know what contingency was made for the circumstance as posed in my question please? If lights travel was being aided then inhibited in one leg, in equal proportions. then it conceptual might arrive back at the detector at the same time as light in the leg perpendicular to it which traveled a constant speed. 

I'm assuming there must be a contingency made for this situation, because people are sure of their experimental conclusions. However I am not aware of the contingency please?

Comment: What trouble are you having with calculating this scenario? $v=ds/dt$, from which you get $dt=ds/v$. Substitute the velocities and you can calculate the total time that your Bob would take along the arms of your interferometer.

Comment: Please take what @CuriousOne says seriously and calculate the travel time of the scenarios you suggest. The two walkers *don't* take the same time in the course of the trip. Really. Do the math in detail.

Comment: I'm curious why wouldn't the times be the same? Say the distance is 3 km one way and 3 km back again. Traveling with the escalator is 3 km/h and traveling again's the escalator is 1 Km per hour. Wouldn't that be a four hour round-trip for either paths?

Comment: @BillAlsept: The velocities are in the denominator, not in the numerator. 1/3+1/1=4/3, which is not the same as 1/2+1/2=1.

Comment: In your example set the escalator speed to 2km/hr. Bob now takes an infinite time to return on the leg with the escalator because his net return speed is zero.

Comment: So how long would it take to walk 3 km against the escalator?

Comment: Beautiful, thank you guys.
Bob walks one of the 2km long interferometer legs at 2 km / hr. So it takes him one hour each way, total two hrs.
Twin Bob walks the adjacent 2 km leg, however aided by an escalator at an additional 1 km / hr. Traveling at 3 km / hr it takes him 40 mins to reach the furthest point of the leg. On turning around, the escalator begins to impede his progress. Walking at 2 km / hr against a 1 km / hrs escalator, he makes headway at 1 km / hr, it takes him 2 hrs to travel the 2 km. Added together, it took him 2 hrs 40 mins in comparison to the other bobs 2 hrs.

love it

Comment: I had forgotten that the paths were perpendicular. I was thinking they were opposite directions and therefore assumed the time would be the same.

Comment: I can't imagine a aether anyway. Especially one that moves in One Direction. The way I see it is no matter how fast a source is moving when it emits a photon the Photone moves away at the speed of light whatever direction it goes.

Comment: But that is why this subject is so interesting. As you put it, "light just traveling one speed no matter circumstance or direction" is a perfectly logical idea, but not enough to explain the experimental results. But it must be true to some extent, because photons red or blue shift when we move towards a source of light, and or away. Coz we're passing wave crests more or less frequently depending on our own relative motion to the light. So what you say is also true, but there must also be something else going on. As perplexing as this is, I believe there to be a reasonable answer. But what?

Answer (score 2):

> So the other bob who travelled at 2 km/hr the whole time, makes up
>   ground on the other bob on the return journey, and they arrive home at
>   the same time as each other.

You have missed an important feature of the experiment.
The escalator (ether wind) is in action for all Bob's movements; both up and down the escalator as well as Bob walking "across" the escalator.

Comment: Will you please elaborate Farcher?

Comment: Have a look at this website including the swimming example. http://galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu/lectures/michelson.html